# How to make this shape responsive? Changing values on borders does not work

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have found the following shape which I want to make responsive:

```css
#hexagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}
#hexagon:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagon">
```

If I'm changing the values of `border-left`, `border-right` or `border-top` in percentages, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you change them - show the change. Provide a working example.

Comment: @Dekel: Added working example.

Comment: Change the unit from px to vw for each value: https://jsfiddle.net/wqbLvewh/2/

Comment: I don't see any percentages in your example

Comment: @GolezTrol: I want to place this item in the middle of two other divs. Changing dimensions to vh,vw increases its size too much.

Comment: You can use different values if you want it smaller. For instance divide every value by 2: https://jsfiddle.net/wqbLvewh/3/  Or you could experiment with `transform: scale(n)`.

Comment: Another alternative, arguably better, is to use SVG.

Comment: Its better to change triangle width on each break point instead of making it fluid responsive.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman: Wouldn't that be a lot of coding?

Comment: @FahadUddin It depends on how much break-points you are using. As for me there should be 3 or 4 maximum not more unless very necessary.

Comment: use `vh, vw` units, if not worried about older browsers.